# UIButton changes height after setBackgroundImage

Tags: uibutton

This is with ios 6.x, simulator and on-device, xcode 4.6.

I have a RoundRect button in a storyboard that is linked to an outlet in my code. In `viewDidLoad`, I do the following:

```
UIImage *bgImage = [[UIImage imageNamed: @"bgButton.png"]
        resizableImageWithCapInsets: UIEdgeInsetsMake(8, 8, 8, 8)
                       resizingMode: UIImageResizingModeStretch];
[ButtonOutlet setBackgroundImage: bgImage
                        forState: UIControlStateNormal];
```

The button is has a height of 44 in the storyboard and there is no code that changes it, however with the `setBackgroundImage` call `viewDidAppear` reports the height of the button frame as 52, without that call it's still 44. The background image is a 36px square (72@2x). The size of the insets doesn't appear to make a difference.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding a constraint in interface builder for the height of the affected button fixed the problem.